# Does Parse (objective-c) Framework have a limit on channels?

Tags: objective-c, frameworks, push-notification, parse-platform

Does [Parse](http://parse.com) have a limit on the number of channels I can have? I am trying to send a push notification to individual users and the only way I can figure out how to do that is to set up a channel for each user. Other question: Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I emailed Parse and this was the response I got:

> Nope, there's no limit on channels. We'll be providing a better way to push to a specific user pretty soon. I'll put you down to get notified when it's ready.

EDIT:

A recent email from Parse about the 'better way':

> I wanted to let you know that you can now push directly to a user on iOS, provided you are sending notifications via the REST API. This blog post has more information: http://blog.parse.com/2012/07/06/pushing-to-queries-in-ios/ . You can also target push notifications by device token, geographical region, or according to any other data that you store on a per-device basis.